# Nuxt: Create a plugin that automatically adds a computed to component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I would like to create a Nuxt plugin that automatically adds a computed to components that have a certain property (without using a mixin).

For example, any component that have a `addComputedHere` property:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  computed: {
    myComputed: () => 'foo'
  },
  addComputedHere: true
}
```

would turn into:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  computed: {
    myComputed: () => 'foo',
    injectedComputed: () => 'bar' // Injected
  },
  addComputedHere: true
}
```

So far, I'm not sure what's the best solution among using a Nuxt plugin/module/middleware or simply a Vue Plugin (if it's feasible).

How would you do it?

Comment: This would only be possible through a mixin.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is in the same case, I found a solution by creating a Vue plugin that applies a mixin to customize the component in `beforeCreate`:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

const plugin = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.mixin({
      beforeCreate() {
        if (this.$options.addComputedHere) {
          this.$options.computed['injectedComputed'] = () => 'bar';
        }
      }
    })
  }
};

Vue.use(plugin);
```